# modifying option text in ubercart attributes

Tags: ubercart

I am made an attribute with mulitple options on my Ubercart Product. I made an adjustment to the price of some of the options ie: -38 (its 38 less dollars) but now on the dropdown, it has the option name followed by ', -$38.00). How can I get rid of this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to this URL in your Drupal site:

   *admin/store/settings/products*
2. You will find a list of menu in that click `Attribute settings`
3. You will option for price format in that select the first radio button `do not display`